# Invalid component positions when mouse listener on JTable fires

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to when I click on a cell on `JTable` some text changed in a label in `JFrame`. I write below code; but when I click, the components' positions  are destroyed, and I see a rearranged gui. I didn't get any exception in log file, too!

The part of code for `JTable` mouse listener: (`x` is a `JTable`)

```
x.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        try {
            String temp = (String) model.getValueAt(x.getSelectedRow(), 0);
            Class.forName(Configure.driver);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Configure.url
                + Configure.dbName, Configure.userName, Configure.password);

            java.sql.PreparedStatement prs2 = con.prepareStatement(
                "select count(*) as tedad from messages where receiver=?");

            prs2.setString(1, temp);
            temppResultSet = prs2.executeQuery();
            if (temppResultSet.next()) {

                int RecNum = temppResultSet.getInt("tedad");
                System.out.print("RECEIVED NUM: " + RecNum);

                numberOfMessageReceiveByuser.setText("dsdsdsaf");//LABEL NAME
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
});
```

Comment: i bold the main line with //LABEL NAME

Comment: Alternatively, consider `MouseAdapter`, `ListSelectionListener` or `TableModelListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solved.
i set all of positioned of my components statically(not with layout manager).
when you want to set positions statically you should set component layout to null with .setLayout(null)
that was the finger note i forget to do!